# Google Maps 'station' in json output

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, public, transit

i've a question about Google Maps Public Transportation, i want to fetch all data from Google Maps to my smartphone. I've here an url, that gives me the data as json format.

**JSON :** 
[JSON Output](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=M%C3%BCnchen,%20Deutschland&destination=Richter+Frenzel,%20Maria-Probst-Stra%C3%9Fe%2021,%2080939%20M%C3%BCnchen,%20Deutschland&sensor=false&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit)

**Google Maps:** 
[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/M%C3%BCnchen+ZOB+(Hackerbr%C3%BCcke),+M%C3%BCnchen,+Deutschland/Richter%2BFrenzel,+Maria-Probst-Stra%C3%9Fe,+M%C3%BCnchen,+Deutschland/@48.1683927,11.535658,13z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e76074d5093e5:0x83de25f1eb56460b!2m2!1d11.549807!2d48.142451!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e743fd7bed34f:0xa9dc727353a27ea2!2m2!1d11.595258!2d48.193127!3e3)

But i can't see the stations in json file. Following image shows the stations names(marked in yellow).

[image]

How can i get the all station names in json format? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that these stations are available, because they are not relevant for the route(the traveller will simply pass this stations, but no action is required)

Comment: thanks for your reply Dr.Molle, i will look for another solution to fetch the station names.